# Android Room: Efficient way to transform json result into db object

Tags: android, type-conversion, normalization, android-room, pojo

## **Problem**

I have a POJO parsed from an API call which looks like this

```
public class Article {

  public Long id;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("section")
  public String section;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("title")
  public String title;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("topics")
  public List<String> topics;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("media")
  public List<Media> media;
}
```

For the sake of minimizing redundancy and duplicates, I am looking to create a schema like this

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = { 
          @ForeignKey(entity = Article.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "articleId"), 
          @ForeignKey(entity = Topic.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "topicId"),
          @ForeignKey(entity = Media.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "mediaId")
}
public class Articles {

    @PrimaryKey
    public Long articleId; 

    @ColumnInfo(name = "topic_id")
    public Long topicId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "media_id")
    public Long mediaId;
}

@Entity
public class Article {
    // Left out
}

@Entity
public class Media {
    // Left out
}
```

As you can see, when I call the DAO methods to access the database, I can not just pass in the pojo object directly (unless I am mistaken about this). I believe I need to transform the object to one which matches the database entity model.

## **Question**

Does the Android Framework provide a natural way to convert from POJO to the database model object? Is there a way to do this other than manually converting it myself?

## **Things I've Tried**

- I know that I can implement the conversion inside a method within my DAO interface. But then I would have to create a new object and set all the values manually.
- I initially thought typeconverters would work but they seem to convert individual columns.

Comment: simply create a type converter class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is use **`@Embedded`** annotation for your POJO(Model Class) which will refer to another class. then create a type converter class.

```
@Embedded(prefix = "media")
private Media media;

@TypeConverters({TypeConvertorClass.class})
@Database(entities = {Article .class,Media.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class `DataBaseExample` extends RoomDatabase {
}


public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<String> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }
 
    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }
}


public class TypeConvertorClass {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Media getMedia(String longId) {
        return longId== null ? null : new Meida();
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "Article")
public class Article {
    @ColumnInfo (name = "article_id")
    public Long id;
    
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("section")
    public String section;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("topics")
    public List<String> topics;

    @Embedded(prefix = "media") // We need relation to Media table
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("media")
    public List<Media> media;
}

public class Media {
    @ColumnInfo (name = "media_id")
    public Long id;
}
```

Comment: I can see that typeconverters does simplify the process. But how does it handle the case where I need to query from list type objects like "topics". What if I wanted to get all articles with a certain topic? If I separated "topics" into its own entity, I believe I could do this with a select and join query. Does it still work if I use typeconverters?

Comment: I don't think you can use a query in the `DAO` to annotate over a list that is held as a value in one of the columns. You would probably have to select each list out and for/while loop over the values to match. You CAN match to a specific object that uses the `TypeConverters` with some creative `@Query` statements, like: `@Query("Select article_entry Where media = :mediaItem)
abstract void loadArticleByMediaItem(Media mediaItem);`

Comment: @Kevin.Lam if you want to query topic, all you can do is just pass topic to your method while querying and get your desired result .

Comment: in you Dao simply use query.
    @Query("SELECT * FROM topic where topic.topic LIKE :topic")
    List<Topic> getSpecificTopicList(String topic);

Comment: I would agree to @AtifAbbAsi , that is why we are using `TypeConverters` in the first place, i haven't tried it yet but i think it will work for you

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi I am confused on how @Query("SELECT * FROM topic where topic.topic LIKE :topic") would work in this case. If you mean querying inside the Article table, wouldn't the query not find a match? The typeconverter would just convert the String value back into List<String> topic which "LIKE :topic" would not match properly. Also I am trying to get a List of Articles by topic so List<Article> getArticlesByTopic(String topic);

Comment: Just read through another stackoverflow post. The query works because it searches through the converted topic string for similar topics. I will be using typeconverter. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Kevin.Lam "Just read through another stackoverflow post"? ANY? How could it help? You should be more specific about which one.

Comment: @The incredible Jan My mistake about not adding a link to the stackoverflow post. It's been some time, so I don't remember which post I was referring to. The idea behind it was that I previously was under the wrong assumption that the "LIKE :topic" query would be performed on the list of topics (List<String>) rather than the String of topics. It works because it's done on the latter

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@Embedded** annotation for your related POJO which refers to another class.

You can do like this:

**Article.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Article")
public class Article {
    @ColumnInfo (name = "article_id")
    public Long id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("section")
    public String section;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("topics")
    public List<String> topics;

    @Embedded // We need relation to Media table
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("media")
    public List<Media> media;
}
```

**Media.java**

```
public class Media {
    @ColumnInfo (name = "media_id")
    public Long id;
}
```

So now on, you can directly use this **POJO** as Entity for **ROOM**.

---

**Please note:**

*Though i'm not sure about how you'll handle that relation (because, Media obj is in list for Article class, you'll need to use type converter for that)*

Reference from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#nested-objects)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Database) "There is no limit on the number of Entity or Dao classes but they must be unique within the Database." So I think you can simply declare the different classes within your database class that extends `RoomDatabase`.

Have you tried simply declaring the different POJOs as different entities and including them all in the same database class?

For instance:

```
  // Article, Topic and Media are classes annotated with @Entity.
  @Database(version = 1, entities = {Article.class, Topic.class, Media.class})
  abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
  // ArticleDao is a class annotated with @Dao.
  abstract public ArticleDao articleDao();
  // TopicDao is a class annotated with @Dao.
  abstract public TopicDao topicDao();
  // MediaDao is a class annotated with @Dao.
  abstract public MediaDao mediaDao();
}
```

This may not exactly help with the redundancy, but my initial thought would be type converters as well. I've actually successfully even implemented a `parcelable` object as a column within my `Room Database` using `TypeConverters` and a single `Dao`.

Have you tried using `Gson` in your `TypeConverter` class? I believe [this article](https://medium.com/@amit.bhandari/storing-java-objects-other-than-primitive-types-in-room-database-11e45f4f6d22) addresses your question more directly. It's a guide to storing objects in a room database. Again, the trick is in the type converters and declaring your object as the type token for Gson. For instance:

```
public class Converters {
   @TypeConverter
   public static List<Media> fromStringToList(String mediaListString) {
      Type myType = new TypeToken<List<Media>>() {}.getType();
      return new Gson().fromJson(mediaListString, myType);
   }
   @TypeConverter
   public static String fromMediaListToString(List<Media> mediaItems) {
      if (mediaItems== null || mediaItems.size() == 0) {
        return (null);
      }
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      Type type = new TypeToken<List<VideoParcelable>>() {
      }.getType();
      String json = gson.toJson(mediaItems, type);
      return json;
   }
}
```

That addresses the things you've tried. Now on to your statement "I believe I need to transform the object to one which matches the database entity model." Actually, not necessarily. You can use the `@Ignore` annotation for different creation instances or implementations of your entity, so long as there is at least one default constructor that includes the `primary key` of the `entry`. In your case:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = { 
      @ForeignKey(entity = Article.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = 
      "articleId"), 
      @ForeignKey(entity = Topic.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = 
      "topicId"),
      @ForeignKey(entity = Media.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = 
      "mediaId")
}

public class ArticlesEntry {

@PrimaryKey
public Long articleId; 
@ColumnInfo(name = "topic_id")
public Long topicId;
@ColumnInfo(name = "media_id")
public Long mediaId;

private Article articleObject;
private Media mediaObject;

//default constructor
public ArticlesEntry(int id) {
    this.articleId = id;
}

//You can call this anytime you add to the database with media object input
@Ignore
public ArticlesEntry(int id, Media inMedia) {
    this.articleId = id;
    this.mediaObject= inMedia;
}
//You can create many of these and insert as needed, the left out variables of the 
//are null, note that id has to be passed b/c your primary key isn't set to 
//autogenerate
@Ignore
public ArticlesEntry(int id, Article inArticle) {
    this.articleId = id;
    this.articleObject= articleObject;
}
//Or both objects:
@Ignore
public ArticlesEntry(int id, Media inMedia, Article inArticle) {
    this.articleId = id;
    this.mediaObject = inMedia;
    this.articleObject= articleObject;
}

//getters and setters here...

}
```

If you create your `ArticlesEntry` like above, you'll need to make and include the different `TypeConverters`, which can all be within the same class and imported to the specific DB with `@TypeConverters(MyConverters.class)`. Hope this helps!