# How to use JSONObject in Room Database Android

Tags: android, android-room

I am having an issue if I take JSONObject in room database entity.

```
@Entity(tableName = RoomDbConstant.formTable)
data class FormEntity(
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var formId: String,
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("title")
    var formTitle: String?,
    @NonNull
    var formCategoryId: String?,
    @NonNull
    var formSubCategoryId: String?,
    @NonNull
    var formData: String?,
    @NonNull
    var is_active: String? = AppConstants.ACTIVE,
    @NonNull
    var status: String? = AppConstants.NONE,
    @NonNull
    var is_sent_server: String? = AppConstants.NOT_SENT,
    @NonNull
    var tempEntryExisted: Boolean? = false,
    @NonNull
    @Embedded(prefix="FormDataEntity")
    var formDataEntity: FormDataEntity?,
) : Comparable<FormEntity?> {
    override fun compareTo(other: FormEntity?): Int {
        return formTitle?.compareTo(other?.formTitle.toString(), ignoreCase = true)!!
    }
}

data class FormDataEntity(
    @Embedded
    @NonNull
    var response: FormFieldsEntity
)

data class FormFieldsEntity(
    @NonNull
    var is_active: String = AppConstants.ACTIVE,
    @NonNull
    @Embedded
    var fields: ArrayList<FieldEntity>,
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("title")
    var formTitle: String,
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("id")
    var formId: String,
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("gfpdf_form_settings")
    var gfpdfFormSettings: JSONObject,
)
```

I have three classes First class is FormEntity which has sub-class FormDataEntity and that FormDataEntity class has a subclass that has JSONObject. SO I am getting data from api in which there is one JSONObject with the name "gfpdf_form_settings". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzdrH.png)

So I am adding data in room databse when fetching data by converting using GSON from api.

```
val data: FormDataEntity = Gson().fromJson(obj, FormDataEntity::class.java)
                    val formModel = FormEntity(formId.toString(),Utilities.separateTitle(data.response.formTitle)[0].toString()
                        ,mCatId,mSubCatId.toString(),obj,data.response.is_active,
                        AppConstants.NONE,AppConstants.NOT_SENT,false,data)
But not able to do because I get error of roomdatabase.
```

**Engineering Forms/Version 2 Room database offline functionality/EngineeringForm/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/app/engineeringform/controller/database/entities/formEntities/FormFieldsEntity.java:20: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
private org.json.JSONObject gfpdfFormSettings;
^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).**

I have tried every way but not able to find solution how to use JSONObject in entity class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save a `JSONObject` as entity in roomdb. In this case, you may copy the entire `gfpdfForm` JSON into `JSON into Kotlin data class` plugin to make unique data class for it.

You may reference here:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

There are many answer on converting JSON into data class

1. [insert JSON data using Room Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027487/insert-json-data-using-room-library)
2. [Android Room: Efficient way to transform json result into db object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619663/android-room-efficient-way-to-transform-json-result-into-db-object)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, You mean I should try it with POJO classes. I have checked people have used TypeConverters for it but they haven't used it for JSOnObject. So is there any way to use JSONobjects using converters?

Comment: For type-convert, I think u should convert the entire JSON into String and store it in db as String. Check it out in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736604/how-to-store-objects-in-android-room

Comment: so everytime u get this JSON, u can convert it directly into String and store it in db. Then when u want to use it, just retrieve it as String and convert it back to JSONObject. But highly recommend to cast it in POJO as it helps for type-safety.